# Finding the limit of expression used for the central limit theorem

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

We are some folks working on proving the central limit theorem. The missing piece we lack is finding the limit in the following equation for $n \rightarrow \infty$. Maple is able to find a limit, but so far we haven't been succesfull in recreating this analytically by hand.

$$\left(  \left( 1-p \right) {{\rm e}^{{\frac {-i \cdot\theta}{ \sqrt{n}}
 \sqrt{{\frac {p}{p-1}}}}}}+p{{\rm e}^{{\frac {i \cdot\theta}{ \sqrt{n}}
 \sqrt{{\frac {p-1}{p}}}}}} \right) ^{n}
$$

If anybody has any helt with this it will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Use that for $x\to 0$

$$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}2+o(x^2)$$

maybe also first order expansion suffices.